# How to use vlookup to in excel to find the sum of cells 3 columns to the right?

Tags: excel

I am using Excel and I need to find the sum of the cell 3 columns to right of a specific word. This needs to be done through all the sheets in the workbook, The words are in the same 3-4 columns throughout the sheet. I believe I need to use vlookup but am not sure.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck0w2.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the sheet you are working on? Perhaps with annotations that show what/where you are interested in?

Comment: I have added a picture to better show what I need

Comment: [Try this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3960-excel-sum-vlookup-multiple-sheets.html) . This might help you

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot